# Object required, but the object does exist

Tags: vbscript

This worked a couple of times, I gave it to my friend and he started getting an error on line 68. Object required.

```
Line:68
Char: 2
Error: Object required: 'document.all.item(...)'
Code: 800a01a8
Source: VBScript runtime error
```

It takes a website for requesting songs and spams in requests. I have permission to do this. The error wasn't happening, but now it is. Visual Studio is completely up to date. I'm on windows 10. It did work, but now it throws that error.

I already tried updating windows, and visual studio. Also running it in command prompt did not yield any information.

```
Option Explicit

Dim browser,x,loginpass,datem,dated,datey,nameArr,numberOfRequests,artistName,songName

set x = CreateObject("wscript.shell")
'Random init shit'
loginpass = "space"
datem = 5
dated = 4
datey = 2019
'Fill this array with names, and it will loop through all of them when you run it.'
nameArr = Array("Becka","Kelly","Jake","Joseph")
'This will control how many times the selected song is voted for'
numberOfRequests = 5
'What is your song pick?'
artistName = "PinkFong"
songName = "Baby Shark"


Dim ree
ree=msgbox("You selected " & songName & " by " & artistName & ". If that is not correct, click no.", 4096+64+4, "Reeee, make sure you don't request the wrong shitty song!")
If ree = vbNo Then
    WScript.Quit
End If  


Dim name
For Each name in nameArr 'name loop'
    'initialize the browser in the most basic form'
    set browser = createobject("internetexplorer.application")
    browser.statusbar = false
    browser.menubar = false
    browser.toolbar = false
    browser.Width = 1360
    browser.Height = 768
    browser.top = 100
    browser.Left = 100
    browser.Resizable = 0
    browser.visible = true

    'navigate to the login website with the specified djidnumber'
    x.AppActivate "Internet Explorer"
    browser.navigate([sitenameredacted])
    do while browser.busy
        wscript.sleep(100)
    loop

    'input the date and password into the fields provided'
    browser.document.all.item("password").value = loginpass
    browser.document.all.item("month").value = datem
    browser.document.all.item("day").value = dated
    browser.document.all.item("year").value = datey
    wscript.sleep(500) 'This is line 61'
    x.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
    do while browser.busy
        wscript.sleep(100)
    loop

    'Deal with the guestname dialogue befor looping song pick 10 times.'
    browser.document.all.item("guest_name").Click() 'this is the line 68 in question'
    wscript.sleep(500)
    Set x = CreateObject("wscript.shell")
    x.SendKeys name
    wscript.sleep(100)
    x.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
    wscript.sleep(100)

    'Select the button for add your own.'
    browser.Document.getElementByID("addyourown_a").click
    wscript.sleep(100)

    'Loop the song request the number of times given'
    Dim loops
    For loops = 1 to numberOfRequests
        browser.Document.getElementByID("add_your_own_artist_name_id").value = artistName
        browser.Document.getElementByID("add_your_own_song_title_id").value = songName
        For Each btn In browser.Document.getElementsByTagName("input")
            If btn.value = "Save" Then btn.Click()
        Next
        wscript.sleep(100)
    Next

    'Submit requests and then close browser for the next name to start.'
    For Each btn In browser.Document.getElementsByClassName("djep-guestsubmit")
            If btn.href = "javascript:document.ep_form.submit();" Then btn.Click()
    Next

    wscript.sleep(5000)
    browser.Quit

 Next 'name loop'
```

I expect it to set the login info on the site, and then login. Afterwards it inputs the first name on the list and confirms a dialogue. Then, it suggest the same song 5 times. That works flawlessly when I separate it.

When I add a 5 second wait time to line 61 instead of a .5 second wait time nothing changes so I assume the error is above line 61.

Comment: Note: Some comments above the `Option Explicit` are omitted so the line numbers are off. I numbered the ones in question with a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I actually fixed this. The problem is the line x.SendKeys {ENTER}

Enter doesn't actually advance the dialogue, so it was looking for an element that didn't exist yet, guest_name